# What does geeko@buildhost signify in linux version?

Tags: linux, suse

On a linux server when checking the Linux version I see the following "geeko@buildhost"

```
Version:  Linux version 4.12.14-95.54-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Thu Jun 4 12:49:28 UTC 2020 (892ef1f)
```

What does this signify? does it have something to do with who built the os packages?

Comment: What it generally signifies is the host within SuSE/openSUSE Build Service that compiled and created the package. (it isn't important for anything else) It looks like you are running SLE instead of openSUSE (unless that is what tumbleweed shows). This is better asked on `packaging@lists.opensuse.org`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply an identifier showing the user and host names where the kernel is compiled. The former is the result of executing `whoami` and the latter is the result of running `uname -n`. You can see how it is put together in [`init/version.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/init/version.c):

```
const char linux_banner[] =
    "Linux version " UTS_RELEASE " (" LINUX_COMPILE_BY "@"
    LINUX_COMPILE_HOST ") (" LINUX_COMPILER ") " UTS_VERSION "\n";
```

The variables are set by [`scripts/mkcompile_h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/mkcompile_h):

```
if test -z "$KBUILD_BUILD_USER"; then
    LINUX_COMPILE_BY=$(whoami | sed 's/\\/\\\\/')
else
    LINUX_COMPILE_BY=$KBUILD_BUILD_USER
fi
if test -z "$KBUILD_BUILD_HOST"; then
    LINUX_COMPILE_HOST=`uname -n`
else
    LINUX_COMPILE_HOST=$KBUILD_BUILD_HOST
fi
```